# App Fabric Cache Monitor

Tags: azure, appfabric

With the App Fabric Cache there are limits to the number of transactions per hour. Is there any way to monitor this? Firstly for testing, to find out how much cache we will need, and primarily so we don't hit the limit and have the site go down because we can't access the cache any more.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use the Azure Application Manager as explained in this blogpost:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2011/06/20/introducing-windows-azure-appfabric-applications.aspx

there are some opensource tools available on codeplex as well:
http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=azure%20monitor&ac=3

i usually stick to the azure provided tools..

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is nothing in the management portal or in any in of the APIs that you can use to determine how many transactions you've used against the cache in any given hour (or how many connections you're using, the other limiting factor when using app fabric cache).

If this is particularly important you might try building a wrapper around cache access and use a [scalable counter](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/architecting-scalable-counters-with-windows-azure) which increments every time you perform a transaction.

Comment: This is fairly important as when the cache reaches it's limits the connections will be refused, a potential killer for many web sites. I can imagine having to tell my users when their application is down, don't worry it will be up in 20 minutes. They won't be happy.